# Is there a word for "scream" in a musical context?

Tags: word-choice

I want to say something along the lines of "I want to hear more of [name's] screams" but I don't want to sound like a psychopath. I mean the sort of scream you'd hear in a metal song. Is there a word for that?

Right now I have: AさんとBさんの叫{さけ}び声{ごえ}がもっと聞​きたいです。

Comment: I posted an answer, but maybe I am not sure if you are asking/thinking that 叫さけび声 is wrong or non appropriate for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

Since I got banned once because of my opinions on katakana, I guess I would try to make it right by giving a katakana answer. Besides, I'm quite a metalhead myself.

叫【さけ】び声 is not wrong. Actually you can find articles [like this](https://gigazine.net/news/20170507-vocal-coach-of-screaming/) using just that word. So, I like that.

However, I think another popular word is スクリーム. It is quite used and understood in the context of metal music to describe that type of singing.

In general, there is a broader category called [デスヴォイス](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B9%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9), that is the equivalent of "death growl" in English.

If you want to be more specific, you can look at [this website](https://ichiranya.com/music/010-death_voice.php) that list all sorts of vocal styles (including scream).

**PS**. Actually, if you check the Japanese wiki for [screamo](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A2), you can find at some point just this sentence:

> エモに特徴づけられる疾走感やポップなメロディラインに**スクリーム、つまり絶叫するように歌うボーカル**をさらに加えたものである.